# Generate serializable classes via XJC without xsd change

Tags: java, serialization, jaxb, xsd, xjc

Is there any way to generate classes implementing `Serializable` with `xjc` without changes in `xsd`?
Initially (and I tried it with no luck) I thought that binding.xml for xjc would do the job but apparently it is not possible without placing globalBindings sections in xsd.
I'm executing xjc from ant task if that is important.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have found a solution.

My bindings.xml

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="./myXsd.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jxb:globalBindings>
        <xjc:serializable uid="1" />
    </jxb:globalBindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

And my ant options:

```
  <xjc schema="./myXsd.xsd" target="../src/java" package="myxsd.xml" extension="true" binding="./binding.xml"/>
```

Comment: Your `bindings.xml` is invalid XML.